# Android draw circle with 8 sections and all sections should be touchable

Tags: android

Hi i need the code for to create a simple circle with eight sections and all sections should be clickable or touchable i should be able to identify which section he has touched.

what i have done is by using canvas i have drawn the cricle by giving width height it uses 8 points of (x,y) to draw the circle then i am trying to identify on which section he has touched by checking the touch event x and y point to the already stored [8 fixed points in which section it falls ] but it is not working please help me

Comment: please post some of your code you already have... it will be easier to help you out

Answer (score 1):

You can try this open source code 
https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu